# Zend Framework Alphabetic list, new entry isn't alphabetised

Tags: zend-framework

I have a list of clubs fetched from a database I then use the following code to alphabetise them and add a title of the first letter above them.

```
<?php
$previousLetter = false;
?>
<?php 
$i=1; // have a counter variable
foreach($this->clubs as $clubs) : ?>
    <?php
$firstLetter = substr($clubs->club_name, 0, 1);
if ($firstLetter != $previousLetter) {
if($i==1){
    echo "<div class='left_class'>"; // open left div
}
?>
    <h3 id="club-link-header"><u><?php echo $firstLetter; ?></u></h3>
<?php } ?>
    <a id="club-link" href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'club-description', 'action' => 'index', 'club_id' => $clubs->id));?>"><br />
    <?php echo $this->escape($clubs->club_name);?></a>
    <?php $previousLetter = $firstLetter; ?>
<?php 
    if($i==25){
        echo "</div>"; //close left div
        echo "<div class='right_class'>"; // open right div
        }

    if($i==50){
        echo "</div>"; //close right div
}

$i++; // increment the counter variable for each loop
endforeach; 
?>
```

the problem is when I add a new entry into the database it isn't alphabetised, it is added to the end of the list.

Comment: Just add an `ORDER BY`-clause to your sql-query.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, it would work if I didn't have the formatting for the list I have.. here is the controller where I initialise the ORDER BY -> http://pastebin.com/XrPMEQD0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in [how you fetch the data](http://pastebin.com/XrPMEQD0):

```
$this->view->clubs = $clubs->fetchAll(); // Fetches the clubs ordered by ID
$select = $clubs->select(); // Does nothing
$select->order('club_name ASC'); // Does nothing
```

You can do this instead:

```
$this->view->clubs = $clubs->fetchAll(null, 'club_name ASC');
```